# How to pass a parameter to createEditor functions of QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, delegates

A software tool has a table filled with two columns: parameter and data. "Data" column have comboBox widget. How to pass the `listData` to the `createEditor` function as a parameter, that I can assign `listCombo` to the `listData`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import pandas as pd

class DataDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, opt, index):
        comboBox = QComboBox(parent)
        listCombo = []
        comboBox.addItems(listCombo)
        comboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)
        comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(comboBox))
        return comboBox

class Window(QWidget):
    singleton: 'Window' = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Software tool")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1800, 900)
        self.mainLayout=QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.UI()
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self._print)

    def UI(self):
        self.sublayouts = {}
        self.buttons = {}
        self._view()
        self._fillTableWidget()
        self.show()

    def _view(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Parameter', 'Data'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        self.sublayouts['table'] = QGridLayout()
        self.sublayouts['table'].addWidget(self.table, 1, 0, 4, 4)
        self.sublayouts['table'].setRowStretch(4, 1)

        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.sublayouts['table'])

        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, DataDelegate(self.table))

    def _fillTableWidget(self):
        listCol = {
            'Parameters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            'Data': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']}
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(listCol)
        listData = self.df['Data'].to_list()
        print(listData)
        for parameter in self.df['Parameters']:
            rowPosition = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(rowPosition)
            self.table.setItem(rowPosition, 0, QTableWidgetItem(parameter))
            dataItem = QTableWidgetItem()
            self.table.setItem(rowPosition, 1, dataItem)
            self.table.openPersistentEditor(self.table.item(rowPosition, 1))

    def _tableCell(self, text):
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(text)
        return item

    def _print(self):
        print('Item changed:')

def main():
    App=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `createEditor()` is called internally, you cannot pass arguments. Are the contents of `listData` persistent during over the whole application execution?

Comment: @musicamante thank you for explanation! listData are generated at some point during the application execution and after generation it remains the same. I hoped that I could pass it as a parameter to createEditor(), but since it is impossible I solved the problem by declaring listData global variable. Probably it is not pythonic, but it worked. Any suggestion for making it more correctly are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to set a default list as an *instance* attribute of the delegate, use that list within `createEditor()` and overwrite it when the model is retrieved:

```py
class DataDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items = []

    def setItems(self, items):
        self.items[:] = items

    def createEditor(self, parent, opt, index):
        comboBox = QComboBox(parent)
        comboBox.addItems(self.items)
        comboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)
        comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.commitData.emit(comboBox))
        return comboBox

class Window(QWidget):
    # ...

    def _view(self):
        # ...
        self.dataDelegate = DataDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, self.dataDelegate)

    def _fillTableWidget(self):
        listCol = {
            'Parameters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            'Data': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']}
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(listCol)
        listData = self.df['Data'].to_list()
        self.dataDelegate.setItems(listData)
        # ...
```

Note: the `currentTextChanged` signal should be used when you *actually* need it (which is normally required for editable comboboxes, and might not be fired in certain situations); while that signal is usually emitted for uneditable combo boxes even when the same text exists in different items, that behavior *might* change in the future, and the `currentIndexChanged` is usually preferred, especially for model editors, since the data should only be updated when the editor is actually submitted.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more elegant solution!!!

Comment: @user16613865 You're welcome. Remember, 99.9% of the times you decide to use globals, it's for the wrong reason. Always try to understand where is the problem, where those variables are used and how they should be accessed in the proper way considering OOP patterns.